# Adding Checkbox to Datatables - Jquery & Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables

I am trying to add a checkbox to my DataTable but when I run my project it returns the checkbox in text as it is shown in my controller. How can I get this done from my controller?

When i run the project, i get the checkbox does not render in the template but shows raw text. What is happening ?

```
public function getItem()
{
  $items = Item::all();
  return Datatables::of($items)->addColumn('checkbox', function ($item) {
    return '<input type="checkbox" id="'.item->id.'" name="someCheckbox" />';
  })->make(true);     
}
```

**View**

```
 oTable = $('#users-table').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "{{ route('datatable.getitems') }}",
        "columns": [
            {data: 'checkbox', name: 'checkbox', orderable: false, searchable: false},      
            {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
            {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}        
        ],

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your code:

```
return '<input type="checkbox" id="'.item->id.'" // should be $item
```

The Laravel Datatables package escapes the content of all columns by default – except for `action` column. To exclude your `checkbox` column from escaping you have two options:

1. In `config/datatables.php` search for `action` and add `checkbox` to that array. Note: this will exclude this column globally from escaping
2. add `->rawColumns(['action', 'checkbox'])` to your definition

Comment: how do it get id of the selected row?

Answer (score 1):

it is not necessary to modify the config / datatables.php file, you can modify it directly in the return datatable instruction, adding:

```
->rawColumns(['checkbox','name_column'])
```

You can put it like this:

```
public function getItem()
{
  $items = Item::all();
  return Datatables::of($items)->addColumn('checkbox', function ($item) {
    return '<input type="checkbox" id="'.item->id.'" name="someCheckbox" />';
  })
  ->rawColumns(['checkbox'])
  ->make(true);     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
->editColumn('select_orders', static function ($row) {
            return '<input type="checkbox" name="registrations[]" value="'.$row->id.'"/>';
        })->rawColumns(['select_orders'])
```

#### The Laravel Datatables package escapes the content of all columns by default – except for action column. To exclude your checkbox column from escaping you have two options:

In `config/datatables.php` search for `action` and add checkbox to that array. Note: this will exclude this column globally from escaping

`'raw'       => ['action', 'checkbox'],`

Inside your `datatable.js` file

`{data: 'select_orders', name: 'select_orders', searchable: false, orderable: false},`